# Input value referencing nested child object in redux state not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, reducers

I have a function on redux that takes an object, the path to the value that needs updating, and the value.

I have inputs that value is equal to the value of the object on state.

When the listingObj changes on redux, i need the dom to refresh.

The reason i need this to refesh dom is beacuse i have an autofill with companies and when a user selects a company it updates all the values on the listingObj on redux state accordingly.

Thanks in advance!

```
    //REDUX
     import axios from 'axios';

var initialState = {
    listingObj: null,
}

const GET_UPDATED_OBJ = 'GET_UPDATED_OBJ'

export function updateObj(obj, path, value) {
    if (!path && !value) {
        console.log('obj on mount', obj)
        return {
            type: UPDATE_LISTING_OBJ,
            payload: obj
        }
    } else {
        console.log('updated obj', obj)
        path.split(",").slice(0, -1).reduce((obj, key) => obj[key] || (obj[key] = {}), obj)[path.split(",").pop()] = value;
        return {
            type: UPDATE_LISTING_OBJ,
            payload: obj
        }
    }
}


export default function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case UPDATE_LISTING_OBJ:
            return Object.assign({}, state, { listingObj: action.payload })

        default: return state;
    }
}


    //IN REACT COMPONENT
   import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';
import axios from 'axios';
import { updateObj } from '../../../ducks/reducers/main_reducer'


class PropertyEdit extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            listing_id: ''
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        let user_id = localStorage.getItem('user_id');
        let listing_id = this.props.listingId
        this.setState({
            listing_id: listing_id
        })
        axios.get(`/api/listings/${listing_id}`).then((res) => {
            this.props.updateObj(res.data)
        })
     }

    handleChange = path => event => {
        this.props.updateObj(this.props.listingObj, path, event.target.value)
    };

    render() {
        return (
                <div>
<CompanyNameAutofil />
 <TextField
     id="ownerStreetAddress"
      label="Owner Street Address"
       value={(this.props.listingObj.property.ownerCompany && this.props.listingObj.property.ownerCompany.streetAddress1) ? this.props.listingObj.property.ownerCompany.streetAddress1 : null}
                                onChange={this.handleChange('property,ownerCompany,streetAddress1')}
                            />

                </div>
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return state
}



export default connect(mapStateToProps, { updateObj })(PropertyEdit)
```

Comment: Can you paste the complete code? It will be easier for community to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use redux to update a value, `componentWillReceiveProps` will be called in any components that subscribe to that portion of the redux store. You can use `setState` in `componentWillReceiveProps` to update some values in state which will trigger a `render`. However, if state doesn't need to be updated to reflect the changes you can also use `this.forceUpdate()` which will force the DOM to render again despite there being no change. It is worth noting that `forceUpdate()` should be use sparingly.